# I am having problems with passing angular $scope.variable via $http to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

My end goal is to dynamically update an unordered list on my html page from data received from my Database without having to reload the page.

My First step is to get the list from database based on

`<div ng-init="scenarioid='@Model.SCENARIOID'">`

will try to do an `ng-repeat` inside of a test div in my .cshtml page

```
<div id="test">

</div>
```

I am having problems passing the data back to my MVC Controller.

I have tried a

`'@Url.Action("ConfirmedCorrectList", "Content", "$scope.scenarioid")'`

`'@Url.Action("ConfirmedCorrectList", "Content", "{{scenarioid}}")'`

`'@Url.Action("ConfirmedCorrectList", "Content")/$scope.scenarioid'`

`'@Url.Action("ConfirmedCorrectList", "Content")/{{scenarioid}}'`

Nothing seems to work that way as the MVC Controller always sees `string scenarioID` as null now I am trying to pass `data: something` back to my MVC Controller, but again it always shows as null.

I ask for help understanding and help passing my Variable back to my MVC Controller and a way to confirm that the data successfully arrived back to my cshtml page.

Here is my Angular Module

```
    angular.module('Details', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
        .controller('DetailsMainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http ,$window) {

            $scope.$watch('pfsscenarioid', function () {
                console.log('AngularJS $scope.pfsscenario ID: ' + $scope.pfsscenarioid);
            });

            $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("ConfirmedCorrectList", "Content")',
                    data: { scenarioID: {{scenarioid}} }
                })
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.$watch('data', function () {
                        console.log('Data Returned by $http: ' + $scope.data);
                    });
                }).error(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                    $scope.status = status;
                });
```

my JsonResult on my Controller

```
    public JsonResult ConfirmedCorrectList(string scenarioID)
    {
        //find the scenario by scenario ID
        Scenario Scenario = db.Scenarios.Find(scenarioID);

        //create object of all who have confirmed the scenario correct so far.
        var result = Scenario.ConfirmedCorrectBies
            .OrderBy(x => x.DateConfirmed);

        //return JSON object of result
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

edit:  updated variable scenario to scenarioid since that should have been the scope name.

Answer (score 0):

change ajax call post data as

**data: { "scenarioID": $scope.scenarioid }**

Here **scenarioid** is the model variable to use for generate model.
or it can be of **$scope.scenario.scenarioid**

Comment: changed `data: { scenarioID : {{scenarioid}} }` to `data: {"secenarioID": $scope.scenarioid }`  Still getting a `'System.NullReferenceException'` from the MVC Controller.  `string scenarioID` showing as null by the debugger and so `result` never gets populated.
Checked inspect element it doesn't appear that `$scope.scenarioid` ever gets populated either?  do I need a $scope.$watch to wait for that to get populated?